# Jenkins SSH with two factor authentication

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, two-factor-authentication

I have enabled Google Authenticator on my SSH sever to use their two factor authentication method.

I am trying to run an SSH job from Jenkins but cannot configure it to use the 2FA.

Does anyone know a mod that allows this or a way around it while still keeping 2FA or other additional security on the SSH server.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The point of 2 factor authentication is that both factors are not saved in the same place. Storing both of them (password, token) is against the philosophy of the 2FA.

Set up a new user without 2FA and set up public key authentication. Do not try to misuse things and do complicated stuff without any gain, when you can do it simple.

Comment: There is a gain, If you feel it is complicated, we don't need MFA on many cloud server. Jenkins have some sensitive actions, with which whole oroduts may go wrong it is goes into the non otherised user with leakage of credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any plugin that can handle this and I'm not sure whether there will be one since [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication) has been designed to be used by human users. That contradicts to the idea of an automated CI server.

The security [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) supplies isn't enough for you?